# Cortar e recortar

Tags: significado, etimologia, uso-de-palavras

Diferente de "**re**fazer", quando dizem "**re**cortar" não estão se referindo a *cortar novamente*, e no dia a dia 'corte' e 'recorte' parecem ter o mesmo significado.

> Qual a diferença (ou origem da diferença) entre **corte** e **recorte**?

Answer (score 9):

À parte dos significados do dicionário dos verbos [cortar](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/cortar) e [recortar](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/recortar), como falante nativo de PT_BR eu ouço recortar apenas quando aplicado a uma tesoura, portanto normalmente utilizada para materiais que uma tesoura corta, tais como papel, papelão, cartolina, etc.

Eu nunca ouvi recortar aplicado a outro instrumento ou ferramenta, p.ex. uma faca. Soaria estranho dizer a um garçom numa churrascaria:

> Por favor, *recorte* um pedaço desta carne para mim.

De maneira geral, *cortar* parece ser mais genérico, inclusive se aplicando a usos figurados. No Brasil hoje em dia anda muito em voga a expressão *cortar gastos* e soaria bastante estranho *recortar gastos*.

Answer (score 8):

Eu acho que *recortar* é a combinação do prefixo *re-* com o verbo *cortar* mesmo. Só que no caso de recortar, *re-* não é usado estritamente no sentido de "repetição", mas "mudança de estado".

Cito as entradas correspondentes no Aurélio como referência.

> ### re-
>
> [Do lat. *re-*.]
> **Prefixo.**
>
> 1. = 'movimento para trás'; 'repetição'; 'intensidade', 'reciprocidade'; 'mudança de estado': *ressaca*; *recomeçar, relâmpago*; *reavivar, rebrilhar, revezar*; *refrescar*. [...]
>
> ---
>
> ### recortar
>
> [De *re-* + *cortar*.]
> **Verbo transitivo direto.**
>
> 1. Cortar formando (figuras):
>    *As crianças gostam de **recortar** bichinhos.*
> 2. Separar, cortando:
>    ***Recortou** o anúncio do jornal.*
> 3. Talhar ou cortar de novo, reduzindo:
>    ***recortar** um terno.*
>
> [...]

Também acho possível que o significado "mudança de estado" do prefixo *re-* implica algum sentido de repetição. Por exemplo faz sentido que *recortar* (figuras) (sentido (1)) derive de "cortar e cortar de novo, reduzindo" = "cortar e recortar" (sentido (3)).

Comment: Excelente resposta.

Comment: Eu não concordo com esse segundo significado de recortar. (Só mostra quão ignorante sou, que até discordo de um dicionário!!) Por exemplo, não se diria `recorta-me uma fatia de melão`, nem `recorta-me aí a perna [desse frango assado], e um pedaço de peito para o Jorge`. (A terceira definição, não percebo bem; mas parece ter algum potencial.)

Comment: @ANeves Concordo com você, mas esse segundo significado não tem relevância para a reposta. Se causar confusão, posso apagá-lo.

Comment: Ah, pensei que tinha. Com estes comentários, parece-me que fica suficientemente claro para quem leia.

Answer (score 6):

[Recortar](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/recortar) é especificamente (ênfase minha):

> Cortar uma figura **pelos contornos** para a separar do fundo

Ou seja, é uma versão particular e específica de cortar.

Então, posso cortar um dedo mas não posso recortá-lo.

Comment: E eu não poderia dizer "Cortei o cabelo e não ficou bem, vou agora recortar"?

Comment: Eu perceberia, mas soaria estranho; diria antes "vou cortar de novo".

Comment: É exatamente o que penso.  Eu recorto, geralmente papel, com uma tesoura (separar pelo contorno). E corto com outros objetos cortantes (facas, lâminas, alicate, e também tesoura)  Posso cortar um barbante ou um fio com uma tesoura ou alicate, mas não estarei a recortá-los.

Answer (score 3):

Em *refazer* há o prefixo de origem grega cujo um dos significados é de repetição.

Também encontramos o prefixo em *repaginar*, *repensar* e *rever*.

Já em *recorte* não há prefixo. O *re‑* aqui não dá ideia de repetição. Assim como em: *resto, repolho, reta.*

Comment: Esta já me parece um explicação com alguma lógica. Tens como colocar a fonte dessa informação?

Comment: Interessante! Mas então o fato de "corte" e "recorte" terem significados parecidos é mera coincidência? Geralmente nos casos em que "re-" não aparece como prefixo, a palavra sem o "re-" tem um significado bem diferente, como parar/reparar, portar/reportar, etc..

Comment: Um caso interessante também é passar/repassar. "Repasse" pode ser tanto 'passar novamente' quanto 'transferência', e.g. repasse de verbas. Estes dois "repassar" então poderiam ser entendidos como palavras diferentes?

Comment: Acho que _recortar_ = _re-_ + _cortar_ sim e a analogia com _reta_ ou _repolho_ é incorreta, como tentei explicar na minha reposta.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que corte seria a origem do corte propriamente dito e não o objeto que se separou dele.
Por exemplo: "Aqui está a marca do corte" ou "O corte do cano foi feito aqui".

Recorte seria o que se foi tirado proveniente desse corte, uma parte ou pedaço.
Por exemplo: "Tenho recortes de jornais e de revistas" ou "Possuo recortes de tecido para venda".